# HTML Table with custom scrollbar without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, scrollbar

I have created a HTML table with a fixed header and scrollable body. I want to style the scrollbar to look like the attached image.[table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihKuX.png)

Using webkit, I have changed to colour of the scrollbar but i don't know how add the circle.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #00467f; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-color: #00bce4;
 outline: 1px solid slategrey;
 z-index: 10; }
```

Can this be achieved using only HTML, CSS and Pure Javascript?

Comment: My guess is that you have to implement the whole scrollbar yourself, not just change the appearance of the standard.

Comment: There's a tiny script for that - [`fakescroll`](https://github.com/yairEO/fakescroll)

Answer (score 0):

With a `width: 30px;` and `height: 30px;`, `border-radius: 30px;` gives you a circle, maybe that helps in getting creative.

Comment: I added that to `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` and it stayed the same.